# Из dict заполнить матрицу вхождения слова в предложение в Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7, словари

Дана нулевая матрица `с`.

Дан

`text=[[slovo1, slovo2,..., slovon], [slovo1, slovo4, slovo1,...], ..., [...]]`

и словарь

```
dict={slovo1:1, slovo4:2, slovo6:134, slovo88:4....}
```

Ищу количество вхождений каждого слова в предложение с помощью регулярного выражения

```
for line in text:
    for word in line: 
        k = len(re.findall('\W(word)\W', text))) # c - это число вхождений слова в строке
        c[i][dict('word')] = k #записываю число вхождений слова в строку в j-ый элемент i-ой строки 
    i += 1 #перехожу заполнять следующую строку
```

Необходимо заполнить матрицу таким образом, чтобы элемент стоящий на пересечении ой строки и jого столбца был равен количеству вхождений этого слова в предложение.
Выдает ошибку

> TypeError: expected string or buffer

Подскажите пожалуйста как поправить код.

Comment: Ошибка, собственно, сама за себя говорит. Переменная `text` - это массив, а регулярка хочет поиска по строке. Преобразовывайте массив в строку, например.

Comment: изменил на len(re.findall('\W(word)\W', line)), теперь ищет по строке, но ошибка остается

Comment: Неверно, не по строке. исходя из вашего описания переменная line - это также массив.

Comment: Мне кажется вы пытаетесь изобрести [велосипед](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), причём с треугольными колесами ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

c = []

for line in text:
    cc = []
    for word in line:
        cc.append(len(re.findall(word, ' '.join(line))))
    c.append(list(cc))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 0 # во-первых, отсутствовал счетчик индекса строк матрицы
for line in all_sent:
    for word in line:    
        k = len(re.findall(word, ' '.join(line))) # это посчитает число вхождений слова в строке
        Matrix[i][dict_sent.get(str(word))] = k #записываю число вхождений слова в строку в j-ый элемент i-ой строки 
    i += 1 #перехожу заполнять следующую строку
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter

text = [['The', 'dog', 'is', 'black'], 
        ['The', 'cat', 'is', 'white']]

words = [word for line in text for word in line]
counter = Counter(words)

c = []
for line in text:
    c.append([])
    for word in line:
        c[-1].append(counter[word])
```

---

Содержание переменной `c` после того:

> ```
> [[2, 1, 2, 1], 
>  [2, 1, 2, 1]]
> ```